# Is it possible to hide parts of a mesh where it intersects with another?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, objects

First off I am incredibly new to blender and have been working through my project by searching for tutorials online. However I have an issue I can't find a solution to.

I am working on a Fashion based project. I have an Avatar posed and in the position I would like to keep it, so no need to rig it. on that avatar I would like to layer up a t-shirt with a jacket. Both the jacket and the t-shirt are imported OBJ files from another programme. They were created separately and so when I import them both in place, large parts of the T-shirt mesh poke through the Jacket mesh. Screen shot attached.
[image: T-shirt and Jacket layering conflicts]

Is it possible to Hide parts of the t-shirt mesh that poke out through the jacket, without hiding the whole thing. Essentially I want to be able to use the t-shirt alone as well as layered with the jacket  (and do this lots of times with other garments) so I don't want to edit the mesh.

I want it to be able to be an automated NFT so the jackets and tees (and other garments) will work when randomised regardless of what they're layered with.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can use the Mask modifier to hide some parts of your mesh

Comment: Thanks Moonboots. Will I need to select the parts of the mesh I want to mask first in editor mode. is there a way I can select the mesh in object mode and basically tell it - When this mesh intersects with another, hide wherever it pokes out beneath it. - I realise thats not an easy task but I want to try to get it so when it is automated and an instance doesn't have the jacket, the t-shirt looks fine.

Comment: maybe give a try with the VertexWeightProximity modifier, the jacket will determine what is supposed to be hidden, I'm not sure it will be perfect though

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will work but you could try a *Mask modifier* with a *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier:

Select the body (the t-shirt in your case), select all in *Edit* mode and assign to a new group. Give a *Cloth* simulation to the jacket, a *Collisions* simulation to the body. Give a *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier to the body and a *Mask* modifier. In the *Vertex Weight Proximity* choose the vertex group you've created and select the jacket as *Object*. Also choose *Proximity Mode > Geometry* and click on *Vertex*. Set the *Lowest* and *Highest* values. In the *Mask* modifier choose the vertex group and click on the *Invert* button:

[image]

Now the body should be invisible where the jacket touches it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @moonboots. I think im just struggling to implement what you've suggested as im such a novice to the programme. I'll keep on playing with the settings of what you've said and see if I can make it work, but so far ive had no results. really appreciate the help

Comment: OK but I need more informations to guess where you've made a mistake  ;)