# Is there a way to hide parts of the model that go through the shirt?

Tags: mesh, objects, clipping

There is another model going through the shirt, as you can see, and I would like to know if there is a way to hide the parts of the model passing through the shirt?

[image: Text]

Here the same problem, but already the shirt passes through another model.

[image: Text]

I tried using the method described [here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278882/is-it-possible-to-hide-parts-of-a-mesh-where-it-intersects-with-another)

But I did not achieve the desired result, because in the end the model inside the shirt completely disappeared, and I need it to be visible inside as in the image below.

[image: Text]

It's worth noting that I didn't add the "Collision" and "Cloth" modifiers because I'm not going to use cloth simulation.

Just in case, I will mention that this model is a kind of "Frankenstein", as it was assembled from two other models and was planned to be used in animation in the future.

Comment: Hello you can use the Mask modifier on the body

Comment: Good afternoon. I already tried to use the “Mask” modifier (as mentioned [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278882/is-it-possible-to-hide-parts-of-a-mesh-where-it-intersects-with-another)), but, as I said above, I did not achieve the desired result, since the model inside completely disappeared.

Comment: You need to create a vertex group with the vertices you want to hide then invert the selection in the modifier